# Importing from non sequential columns in Excel to VB.Net DataGridView using OleDb

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, datagridview, oledb

I'm trying to import data from a huge excel file to be used in a VB.Net DataGridView.
My problem is that the columns names appear on Row 4 and the columns are not sequential.
Unfortunately editing the Excel database is not an option as many other tools in the organization uses it in its current format.

This is what I've tried so far and i will really appreciate a solution.

```
    Public Sub GetTable()

    Dim cmd As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6 As String
    Dim cn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=PATH;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    q1 = "select * from [2013$B4:D128]"
    'q2 = "select * from [2013$E4:I128]"
    'q3 = "select * from [2013$M4:M128]"
    'q4 = "select * from [2013$O4:P128]"
    'q5 = "select * from [2013$S4:S128]"
    'q6 = "select * from [2013$U4:U128]"
    cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(q1, cn)
    cn.Open()
    cmd.Fill(ds, "Table1")
    cn.Close()
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    Me.DataGridView1.DataMember = "Table1"

End Sub
```

I tried using UNION in the query but just received an error from Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: If you know the headers you want can't you select only those fields? You don't have to `select *` and pull everything...

Comment: Do you mean the columns headers? how can you use them when you're column names aren't on the 1st row?

Comment: I didn't think that mattered as long as you're providing the query range.  Try `select * from [201$B4:$U128] where 1=2` And iterate through the field names in the resulting recordset.

Comment: Can you specify further? i don't think i fully understood what iterating through field names means. do you mean iterating through the datatable after the sql query to database is done?

Comment: Yes - you should be able to read the field names. That 1=2 was just to avoid selecting any records in this case, since you only need to field names: once you have them you can use them in your original select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Following up from comments above. this is an example using VBA/ADO but illustrates the approach I was suggesting for how to construct your SQL:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim f As ADODB.Field

    oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & _
               ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'"

    oRS.Open "select * from [Data test$A4:E8] where false", oConn


    For Each f In oRS.Fields
        Debug.Print f.Name
    Next f

    oRS.Close

End Sub
```

If you check the output from your VB.NET version you can choose the field names to include in your select statement.